# where to I file itunes connect bugs?

Tags: app-store-connect

It's my first app, I provided 5 different snapshots, it for some reason keep making a dup of the 4th to be the 5th one and the real 5th one is just gone for no reason. Where can I file bugs for these issues?

Comment: @minitech, any reason why down vote this question?

Comment: I didn't downvote. I voted to close. (And if you need a reason for that, see above.)

Comment: Generally, questions about Apple's services (iTunes Connect, etc.) are considered off topic, because they aren't direct programming questions. I voted to close as such, but was overruled by the "not a real question" votes, which may have come (along with the downvotes) from your initial "itunes connect is so buggy and slow" wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're a registered apple developer, file a bug at http://bugreporter.apple.com

and document things well, otherwise your bug will be ignored or not looked seriously at.